# PHP and MySQL Database Search Multiple Tables At One Time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I am trying to make the form search by ID, firstname, and lastname. I want the user to type in either one in the search field and get the results from the database.

Here is the actual form I am using:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="term" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

And here is the form.php

```
<?php
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'test';
$db_password = 'test';
$db_database = 'test';

// Database Connection String
$con = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db($db_database, $con);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>SpeedZone Data Search</title>
        <style type="text/css">
table { border-collapse:collapse; }
table td, table th { border:1px solid black;padding:5px; }
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #ffffff}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #ff0000}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
<form action="form.php" method="post">  
<input type="text" name="term" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />  
</form>  
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {

$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rcrentals WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$term."%' or lastname LIKE '%".$term."%' or id = ".$term;
$r_query = mysql_query($sql); 

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Address</th> <th>City</th> <th>State</th> <th>Zip</th> <th>Phone</th> <th>DL</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Car and Controller</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['address'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['city'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['st'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['zip'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['phone'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['dl'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['carcont'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
                // echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" onclick="return confirm(\'Confirm?\')">Delete</a></td>';
                echo "</tr>"; 
        } 

        // close table>
        echo "</table>"; 

}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where I currently have this: It is only searching the ID. I want to be able to type in the ID, or the firstname, or the lastname, or first and last if possible.

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {

$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rcrentals WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$term."%' or lastname LIKE '%".$term."%' or id = ".$term;
```

**I think there are a few things I will need to change but I am confused and have lost myself in it and cannot solve it. Please help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around `$term` when you compare it with `id`. Otherwise, you'll get a syntax error if it's not a number.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rcrentals WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$term."%' or lastname LIKE '%".$term."%' or id = '".$term."'";
```

Also, this assumes you don't use 0 as an `id`. When a number is compared to a string, the string is converted to a number, and all non-numeric strings get converted to 0 and they'll match that `id`. If that's a problem, you should check whether `$term` is a number first. If it's not a number, use a query that doesn't include the `id` check:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rcrentals WHERE firstname LIKE '%$term%' or lastname LIKE '%$term%'";
if (is_numeric($term)) {
  $sql .= " or id = $term";
}
```

Comment: GENIUS! Thank you Barmar! Solved my problem if I am searching one term at a time. What if I want to search two terms at a time? Like firstname and lastname in the box? Right now it comes back empty.

Comment: Do you mean they should be able to enter "John Smith" in the box, and it should check for each word in either field?

Comment: Try using full-text searching instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: Is the MySQL documentation on full-text search hard to understand?

Comment: I only know LIKE and OR - I am not sure about full-text searching.

Comment: That's what documentation is for, anything I write would just be copying from the documentation, which is a waste of my time.

Comment: Thought you could help me out and show me, which is how I learn best. Sorry if I wasted your time. I learn better by seeing. I have read about it and don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks coorect to me. 
Try using braces to separate out OR conditions

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rcrentals WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$term."%' or (lastname LIKE '%".$term."%') or (id = ".$term);

Comment: Parentheses are only necessary if you need to override precedence of multiple conditions, you don't need them around each condition.